# Error uploading file. An unrecoverable error occurred

Tags: nodes, entities

I've been troubleshooting a form in Drupal 7 that has two file upload fields.

If you upload a file with one field, then the other, the second upload will usually give an error. This occurs regardless of the order that the files are uploaded. The error does not occur if the files are both added to the "Choose File" fields and the **whole page** is submitted at once with the save button. The error also does not occur if JavaScript is disabled in the browser, and the individual upload buttons are used.

The easiest workaround I can imagine would be to disable javascript for the form controls on the specific /node/add page, but I do not know how to do this, and I have been unable to find people with a similar need.

The server is PHP/Apache2, with mod_security disabled and with the PHP post size limit and uploaded file size limit set to high limits as per the screenshot. File uploads work normally, leading me to rule out permissions as a culprit.

The watchdog logs and server error_log have no messages of interest, unfortunately.

If anyone has any advice to disable javascript for a page, or to resolve this error, please let me know. Thanks!

[image: first screenshot]
[image: second screenshot]
[image: third screenshot]

Comment: Hey, @fabspro. I am facing same issue today.Can u please provide me your guidance.

Comment: @parth.k I could not resolve this issue, but I worked around it by disabling ajax. And it seems Ivan has given a potential answer below. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is for this line in file.module 
241 --if (empty($_POST['form_build_id']) || $form_build_id != $_POST['form_build_id']) {

You should revise your URL

Comment: From memory, to make it work I decided to disable the AJAX uploading somehow, probably with PHP in a custom module. But now if I find some time I might go back to this website and look into that and see if I can make it work the way it is supposed to.

Comment: Can anyone please explain "You should revise your URL" ?